# tslint and prettier conflict use tslint rules

Tags: javascript, typescript, lint, tslint, prettier

I have `prettier` and `tslint` configured. However it seems prettier overrides the tslint rules. I can disable some of the rules using `.prettierrc`. However I'm still having issues. I want the `tslint.json` /exceptions to take precedence over `.prettierrc`

For instance prettier inserts semicolon at the end of class methods. I have exception in `tslint.json`. but that doesn't seem to work. I could disable with `semi: false` in `.prettierrc` if I do that then it would disable semi every where.

```
// appbar.tsx
const makeStyles((theme) => ({});

export class AppBar {
  private handleOpen = (event: Event): void => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.onOpen();
  }; // prettier inserts semicolon.
}
```

```
{
  "extends": [
    "tslint:recommended",
    "tslint-react",
    "tslint-plugin-prettier",
    "tslint-config-prettier"
  ],
  "rulesDirectory": [],
  "rules": {
    "prettier": true,
    "interface-name": false,
    "quotemark": [true, "single"],
    "semicolon": [true, "always", "ignore-bound-class-methods"] // Doesn't work
  }
}
```

```
{
    "jsxSingleQuote": true,
    "singleQuote": true,
    "semi": false // Disable everything
}
```

```
// appbar.tsx
const makeStyles((theme) => ({}) // Prettier removes semicolon here. Which is not OK. need to keep semicolon

export class AppBar {
  private handleOpen = (event: Event): void => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.onOpen();
  }
}
```

```
import React from 'react' // Disabling in .prettierrc removes semicolon in everywhere.
```

Comment: Upgrade to eslint instead; tslint has been deprecated. I’ve used both prettier and eslint together and setting values in eslintrc in the way you’re doing in tslint.json works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

your tslint.json file seems to be okay, I have to ask though are you sure you installed tslint-config-prettier? and I also don't think you need to add in your rules "prettier": true

here's a link to the official documentation

https://developer.aliyun.com/mirror/npm/package/tslint-config-prettier.

hope this helps though